# Moving Identity Tables to Existing Database for Authentication in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, entity

In my development environment, I have the login and registration working fine with the local db, but when I publish the site live, I am obviously unable to connect to my local db. I'm new to entity framework and I was wondering if there is a way to take the pre-existing identity tables for user information, login, and registration and move it to an existing database. I added the table structure to my MySQL database and changed the connection string to point to it, but am getting the error: "The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context." when attempting to register a user. Any ideas?

Note: I've used the Database first method for this project